# Can 'Custom Field' data be inserted into this Short Code?

Tags: php, custom-field, shortcode

I have created a custom page template. In the template, I use a shortcode for JJ NextGen JQuery Slider. I would like the page to have a 'custom field' called 'Image Gallery' with a value that derives from NEXTGEN Gallery. I am trying to get the page template to recognize the dynamic input of the value from the shortcode but I haven't had success. Any advice is much appreciated! Here is the code I am using:

```
<div id="prop_images">
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[jj-ngg-jquery-slider title="Property" gallery="get_post_meta($post ->ID, 'Image_Gallery', true)" effect="fade" html_id="about-slider" width="400" height="300"]'); ?>
                </div><!-- end prop images-->
```

Answer (score 1):

try creating the string first:

```
    <?php 
    $shortcode = '[jj-ngg-jquery-slider title="Property" gallery="'.get_post_meta($post ->ID, 'Image_Gallery', true).'" effect="fade" html_id="about-slider" width="400" height="300"]';
    echo do_shortcode($shortcode); 
    ?>
```